# ConTeXt : configuration

Tags: context

I searched the doc, but didn't find this...
What is the path in which context searches the environment files ? I'd like to add a personal folder to this path (in my .bashrc), in order to not explicit the absolute path in the source file...

Comment: I am just guessing but is it not the same as for LaTeX and TeX?

Comment: By default ConTeXt searches TEXMF and all directories above the current directory, i.e. if you have `nested/path/to/file.tex` then you can place your environment file in e.g. `nested/env.tex` and it will still be found.

Comment: See also 6.11 of the [ConTeXt Reference Manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf)

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand some things, but I don't see how it may be logical to find this information in the "Getting started" section about the fonts in the manual. I admit I am still not very efficient when searching an information in it... and I try to RTFM before posting. On the plus side, I managed to make my configuration work, thank you for pointing out  TEXMF ; if someone writes a "real" answer with explanations, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @HenriMenke: ConTeXt doesn't search *all* directories above the current directory, but only two levels up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConTeXt searches the `\environment` files in the following order:

1. The current directory (`$PWD` from where `context` is run; **not** the `PWD` of main tex file)
2. The parent directory `../`
3. Grandparent directory `../../`
4. Subdirectories in `$TEXMF/tex/context//`

If you want to store your local environment files somewhere were `context` can find them, store then in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/context/<sub-directory>/`. On Mac/Linux, the default value of `$TEXMFHOME` is `$HOME/.texmf`.

Comment: The $TEXMFHOME possibility is perfect. I don't understand why it isn't mentioned in the manual around section 2.4, when environments are explained...

Comment: ConTeXt follows TeX Directory Structure (TDS, for short). TDS is a beast due to the fact that it has to work on complicated multi-user setups. The most comprehensive source is the TDS manual: http://tug.org/tds/tds.html (Note, I said comprehensive, not easy to read).